# Les expressions « « lâche-moi les baskets » et « s'accrocher aux basques de quelqu'un » sont-elles reliées ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, locutions, origine-ou-raison, anglicismes

On a l'expression populaire « lâche-moi les [baskets](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/basket/8225?q=baskets#8179) » pour « laisse-moi tranquille » (Larousse en ligne). Par ailleurs on a l'expression familière « se pendre, s'accrocher aux [basques](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/basques/8244#locution) de quelqu'un » c'est-à-dire « l'accompagner partout ; ne pas le quitter » (Larousse en ligne). Le fait que l'ordre contenu dans la première consiste ou réfère à ne pas faire ce que l'on fait dans la deuxième, donne l'impression qu'elles participent d'un même paradigme, ce que renforcerait l'homographie partielle il me semble.

Le [faux anglicisme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/basket#Nom_commun_2) *basket* dans l'expression en question procède-t-il ou participe-t-il d'un réaménagement de *basque* dans l'expression familière ; l'usage associé à l'emploi de *basque* en locution sous-tend-il celui avec la *basket* ; ou le locuteur natif le perçoit-il ainsi (relié) ?

Comment: Je suis un francophone du Québec. En fait probablement que depuis un bon moment je confonds _basques/baskets_ dans ces expressions, que je comprends par ailleurs mais que je n'entends pas chez moi, d'où ma curiosité...

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'un francophone de l'Hexagone puisse rapprocher les deux expressions (ni homographie, ni homophonie). Les basques (*baste* → *basquine* → du germanique *bastian* (bâtir - au sens anglais de *baste*)) sont la partie rapportée d'une veste qui part de la taille et descend jusqu'aux (environ) les hanches. S'accrocher aux basques de quelqu'un c'est lui [coller au train](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/coller_au_train), le suivre pas à pas, physiquement.  Si je dis à quelqu'un de me lâcher les baskets, je peux l'employer, comme l'expression précédente, dans un sens spatial

Comment: pour lui dire qu'il arrête de me suivre pas à pas, bien sûr,  mais aussi le lui dire s'il est loin de moi (au téléphone ou tout autre mode de communication à distance) pour lui demander de me laisser tranquille, d'arrêter de me harceler, de me poser des questions, etc. de me « lâcher la grappe ». [Lâcher la grappe](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%A2cher_la_grappe) serait d'ailleurs plus à rapprocher de « coller aux basques », la [grappe](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grappe#fr) pouvant faire partie du matériel de couture.

Answer (score 1):

On s’accroche aux *[basques](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/Basque)* depuis le Moyen-Âge … l’euphonie les a relié aux *baskets* contemporaines.

Ce mot anglophone (né en 1898 selon le petit Robert) aurait traversé la Manche en 1903 et les chaussures auxquelles vous faites référence sont encore plus tardives en France, elles deviennent populaires après la seconde guerre mondiale bien après celles du tennis (le faux ami mentionné dans la question, tennis [chaussures pour ce sport] auxquelles personne ne s’est accroché pour autant) des premiers jours de *[Roland-Garros](http://Roland-Garros)*.

… tout cela plus d’un demi millénaire après la création des basques, avec un ***b*** minuscule pour ne pas offenser les *[Basques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basques)* habitants le Sud-Ouest de l'hexagone et le Nord de l’Espagne
.